# Cannot find the Xpath

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests

[Webpage i want to test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIoYi.jpg)

For this username and password field what will be the Xpath. I am using this below
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs1Dr.png)

When i send keys using those xpath, username and password won't taking any input

I am trying to put values in username and password using stable selectors in selenium.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing I would suggest here is using ChroPath, it helps get the exact rel Xpath. You could use the class name as you have shown but if you want the xpath I would recommend using `"//body/div[1]/div[7]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/input[1]"` for the Account Name, and `"//body/div[1]/div[7]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/form[1]/div[2]/input[1]"` for the password.

Comment: i did take rel Xpath by using ChroPath but it still doesn't take input using sendkeys

Comment: Put the following line before your sendkeys statement.
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(YOUR XPATH HERE)));

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below locators:

for username textfield:

```
.//input[@type='text' and @class='newlogindialog_TextInput_2eKVn']
```

for password textfield:

```
.//input[@type='password' and @class='newlogindialog_TextInput_2eKVn']
```

for sign-in button:

```
.//button[@type='submit' and @class='newlogindialog_SubmitButton_2QgFE']
```

Practice more on XPath and other locators, always prefer Relative XPath, don't use Absolute XPath.

Next time, post your question clearly, not using images.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. But those Xpath you gave here are not working

Comment: what is the error you've got?

Comment: The above locators are working fine for me, I checked them again. If you are facing any error, post that error and post your full code, without that I can't help.

Comment: When i sendkeys using those locator the data i want to send it won't go those input field

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this and modify it for the password:
//div[text()='Sign in with account name']/following-sibling::input

Comment: This xpath not working

Comment: this code works well for me, but I'm using selenide
        open("https://store.steampowered.com/login/?redir=%3Fsnr%3D1_4_661__global-header&redir_ssl=1&snr=1_4_661__global-header");
        $x("//div[text()='Password']/following-sibling::input")
                .shouldBe(Condition.enabled)
                .setValue("aaa");

try to add condition than